# How to use namely correctly

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Is this a correct use of namely:

> We will investigate two different research questions:
>   1. Is there a correlation between age and income?
>   2. Does university education lead to higher income?
>
> From the first two question, a third one arises *namely*: does higher income lead to more happiness?

Comment: Ahhh, the good old days.  "Namely" used to be a common foil for MAD Magazine humor in the '60s and '70s .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Namely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/namely?s=t)* substitutes for "that is". The way you have written it makes it look like you are thinking of it as modifying the verb *arises*, which is incorrect. These are two separate thoughts, and *namely* introduces the second one.

> From the first two questions, a third one arises. Namely, does higher income lead to more happiness?

Or some version thereof.

Comment: I'm not really a "grammarian", but I find it interesting that you would use **...arises. Namely, does...** where @David favours **...arises, namely: does...** My own preference would be for **...arises: namely, does...** but I've no idea what the real [language mavens](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/language_maven) would have to say on the matter.

Comment: @Fumble I used the full stop in my example to make the two separate thoughts as clear as possible, but I would be more likely to use ...arises; namely, does.... I wouldn't use a colon there at all; I don't think it would be appropriate. It's not introducing a list, but rather an addendum to a prior statement.

Comment: On reflection, I agree; semicolon is more appropriate there.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but I would add a comma:

"… arises, namely:  does a higher …"

Also, I would add "a" in a few places:  Does a University education lead to a higher income"

Another nitpick, I rather prefer *greater* to *higher* in this usage.  Higher is more of a comparison of height or altitude than size. Yes it is used (and perfectly acceptable). But, greater is better.

Comment: How about "higher income level" ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Higher describes the level not the income in that case. (*i.e.* the height of the income rather than the size.) Much better fit.  And, as I've said: nitpick.